# since upgrading to mono touch 6.0.0 - i get the following error when trying to run on a real iPhone - but works fine in the simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios

error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Void MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging::void_objc_msgSend_UInt32_IntPtr(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.UInt32,System.IntPtr)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in MonoTouch 6.0.0 when you're using third-party libraries.

You can either recompile your third-party library with MonoTouch 6.0.0, or wait for MonoTouch 6.0.1 to come out later this week.

*Update* The fix has been released